# Use flatMap after method returning Mono<Void>

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm stuck with understanding of some aspects of Project Reactor.

I have the following list of components:

1. Validator of input params, returns `Mono<Void>` or `Mono.error()`
2. Service saving data to db, returns `Mono<Item>`
3. Logger for successful actions of an user, returns `Mono<Void`

A business logic is quite simple: validate params (1), save an item to db (2) and log actions (3). The problem is validator (1) returns `Mono.empty()` if there are no errors with input data and `Mono.error()` if input params contain some errors.

I would like to achieve the next things:

1. If validator returns `Mono.empty()` then continue chain
2. If validator returns `Mono.error()` then immediately stop processing and throw error which will be handled by `exceptionHanlder`

I have tried two options:

First with `.then(Mono<Item> item)` after validation. It allows me to execute saving operation after validation. Given that `.then()` ignores any errors, I can't rise an exception.

```
return inputValidator.validateFields(userId, projectId)
            .then(repository.save(item))
            .onErrorMap(RepoException.class, ex -> new UnexpectedError("Failed to save item", ex))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .doOnSuccess(n -> logService.logActivity(new Activity(adminId, n))
                    .subscribe());
```

Second with `.flatMap(Function<Mono<Void>, <Mono<? extends Item> func)` after validation. This approach can rise an exception from validator, but I can't execute saving operation because `flatMap()` doesn't trigger on empty result.

```
return inputValidator.validateFields(userId, projectId)
            .flatMap(v -> repository.save(item))
            .onErrorMap(RepoException.class, ex -> new UnexpectedError("Failed to save item", ex))
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
            .doOnSuccess(n -> logService.logActivity(new Activity(adminId, n))
                    .subscribe());
```

It is also important to have access for created object after saving (step 2), because I need to pass it to logger service.

Comment: You can't use `flatMap` because there is no `onNext` signal. `then` is a right approach. Not sure why you are saying "Given that .then() ignores any errors, I can't rise an exception"  because `repository.save(item)` will not be resolved in case `inputValidator.validateFields` returns `onError` signal. `save` will be called but this is just assembly time (not subscription time). Check https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription for details

Comment: I got a couple of tests validating behaviour of my service. And they fail with approach with `then()`, because actually `save()` method triggers each time even if errors have occurred after validation. As I understand from docs, all errors happen before `then()` will be replayed in publisher after `then()`. But this is behaviour that I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Not sure how you tested it but publisher in `then()` will not be resolved in case of error. but let me post some same test as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use `flatMap` because there is no `onNext` signal - use `then` instead. Not sure what do you mean by "called" but there is a difference between [Assembly and Subscription time](https://spring.io/blog/2019/03/06/flight-of-the-flux-1-assembly-vs-subscription) in reactive. Publisher you  specified in `then` will not be resolved in case `inputValidator.validateFields` returns `onError` signal.

Here is a test for failed validation and as you may see subscription was not triggered

```
@Test
void saveWasNotCalledIfValidationFailed() {
    var saveMock = PublisherProbe.of(Mono.just("id"));

    var repo = mock(Repository.class);
    when(repo.save())
            .thenReturn(saveMock.mono());

    var res = validateFields()
            .then(repo.save())
            .onErrorMap(IllegalArgumentException.class,
                    ex -> new IllegalStateException("Failed to save item", ex)
            );

    StepVerifier.create(res)
            .expectError(IllegalStateException.class)
            .verify();

    saveMock.assertWasNotSubscribed();
}

private Mono<Void> validateFields() {
    return Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException("oops"));
}

public static class Repository {
    public Mono<String> save() {
        return Mono.just("id");
    }
}
```

and here is a test for passed validation

```
@Test
void saveIsCalledIfValidationPassed() {
    var saveMock = PublisherProbe.of(Mono.just("id"));

    var repo = mock(Repository.class);
    when(repo.save())
            .thenReturn(saveMock.mono());

    var res = validateFields()
            .then(repo.save())
            .onErrorMap(IllegalArgumentException.class,
                    ex -> new IllegalStateException("Failed to save item", ex)
            );

    StepVerifier.create(res)
            .expectNext("id")
            .verifyComplete();

    saveMock.assertWasSubscribed();
}

private Mono<Void> validateFields() {
    return Mono.empty();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about your point about "Publisher you specified in then will not be resolved in case inputValidator.validateFields returns onError signal.". If you look at the docs then you'll find a reason why it works in different way. We may look se the following phrase here "In other words ignore element from this Mono and transform its completion signal into the emission and completion signal of a provided Mono<V>. Error signal is replayed in the resulting Mono<V>." https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then-reactor.core.publisher.Mono-

Comment: Please run tests that clearly show the behavior.

Comment: If you add `verifyError` instead of `expectError` in your first case, you'll ensure that it works as you didn't expected. `expectError` just verifies that there was an element of type `error` in your source. Then you subscribed to it with second step and added `onErrorMap` function which handling error thrown after first step. It's completely another way of pipeline. I'm trying to avoid subscription on the second step if errors have occurred.

Comment: Not sure why you are keep arguing. Please post test that proves that there is a subscription to save

Comment: I've checked it again and noticed that I was completely wrong. I was trying to check that there was no an invocation of the publisher, but I had to check that there is no subscription to the second publisher. I mark your answer as the solution. Thank you for your help!!!